# Interpretation of higher direct images

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

In my algebraic geometry course the higher direct images $R^i f_* \mathcal{F}$ of a sheaf of abelian groups $\mathcal{F}$ on a topological space $X$ were introduced as the right-derived functors of the pushforward $f_*$.

While I have a good intuition of what the pushforward is supposed to do (thinking about pushforwards of vector bundles in differential geometry), I have know idea about how to visualize the higher direct images.

Is there any concept from differential geometry which is analogous to higher direct images or any other interpretation?

Comment: A particular enlightening case to consider is when $f : X \to Y$ is a proper submersion and $F = \underline{\Bbb{Q}}_X$. In this case $R^if_*F$ are local system with stalks $(R^if_*F)_y = H^i(X_y, \Bbb Q)$.

Answer (score 5):

The higher right derived functors generalize cohomology. If you take the map $X$ to a point, then the right derived functors are exactly the cohomology of the the global sections functor. In particular, cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb Z$ gives singular/cw/de-rham cohomology.

You should think of the higher derived functors as a way to patch together the cohomology of the fibers $X_y$ for a map $X\to Y$.

Comment: This. To make this stick intuitively, it's good to remember that this implies that for $0 \to F \to G \to H \to 0$ on $X$, you then get a l.e.s. on $Y$ that begins $0 \to f_* F \to f_* G \to f_* H \to R^1 f_* F \to \cdots$. In this setting, ordinary Grothendieck vanishing (no cohomology in degrees higher than $\dim X$) morally becomes "no $R^i f_*$ for $i\geq$ maximal fiber dimension," but I don't think I know a precise statement (here's a fairly general version for quasicoherent sheaves on nice schemes: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88587/vanishing-of-higher-direct-images).